# RSelenium RemoteDriver not connecting to port 4445L

Tags: r, docker, selenium, rselenium

I have been following the Docker/RSelenium tutorial here: https://docs.ropensci.org/RSelenium/articles/docker.html

I have successfully hosted my own Selenium server:

```
# sudo docker ps

CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                             COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
0c673ba37477   selenium/standalone-chrome:88.0   "/opt/bin/entry_poin…"   3 minutes ago   Up 3 minutes   5900/tcp, 0.0.0.0:4445->4444/tcp   zealous_shannon
```

When I run the following commands, per the tutorial:

```
library(RSelenium)
remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4445L)
remDr$open()
```

I get the following output with no error message:

```
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$id
[1] NA
```

The expected output is:

```
## [1] "Connecting to remote server"
## $applicationCacheEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $rotatable
## [1] FALSE
## 
## $handlesAlerts
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $databaseEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $version
## [1] "45.0.2"
## 
## $platform
## [1] "LINUX"
## 
## $nativeEvents
## [1] FALSE
## 
## $acceptSslCerts
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $webdriver.remote.sessionid
## [1] "644c353a-34b8-4bb4-bcff-746df5a30af8"
## 
## $webStorageEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $locationContextEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $browserName
## [1] "firefox"
## 
## $takesScreenshot
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $javascriptEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $cssSelectorsEnabled
## [1] TRUE
## 
## $id
## [1] "644c353a-34b8-4bb4-bcff-746df5a30af8"
```

This prevents me from proceeding with the tutorial. Any idea why my connection via the RemoteDriver is not working properly?

Comment: Can you try to access the continer with the IP address `remDr <- remoteDriver(
  remoteServerAddr = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx",
  port = 4445L
)`

Comment: I tried that with `remDr <- remoteDriver(remoteServerAddr = "localhost", port = 4445L)`, but no luck.

Comment: Are you on windows, macOS or linux? If you are on windows the IP is not `localhost`, you will need to get it with `docker-machine ip` .

Comment: Also, I noticed that you use `chrome` so set `browserName = "chrome"` in the connection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the connection parameters correctly for the operating system you are using and the browser. If the image is based on `chrome` browser and the default configuration of the driver is `firefox`.

To change this you will need to add the `browserName = "chrome"`. I suggest to always add the server's IP address for clarity so, add `remoteServerAddr = <<server IP>>`

The way to find out what are the default parameters for the driver is to inspect the instantiated remote driver `remDr` will show you what is the default configuration for the driver.

```
>remDr
$remoteServerAddr
[1] "localhost"

$port
[1] 4445

$browserName
[1] "firefox"

$version
[1] ""

$platform
[1] "ANY"

$javascript
[1] TRUE

$nativeEvents
[1] TRUE

$extraCapabilities
list()
```

So after setting the correct parameter, I was able to connect to the RSelenum on the exposed port.

```
library(RSelenium)
> remDr <- remoteDriver(
+   remoteServerAddr = "localhost",
+   port = 4445L,
+   browserName = "chrome")
> remDr$open()
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
$acceptInsecureCerts
[1] FALSE

$browserName
[1] "chrome"

$browserVersion
[1] "88.0.4324.150"

$chrome
$chrome$chromedriverVersion
[1] "88.0.4324.96 (68dba2d8a0b149a1d3afac56fa74648032bcf46b-refs/branch-heads/4324@{#1784})"

$chrome$userDataDir
[1] "/tmp/.com.google.Chrome.egZzL9"


$`goog:chromeOptions`
$`goog:chromeOptions`$debuggerAddress
[1] "localhost:36841"


$networkConnectionEnabled
[1] FALSE

$pageLoadStrategy
[1] "normal"

$platformName
[1] "linux"

$proxy
named list()

$`se:options`
$`se:options`$cdp
[1] "http://172.17.0.2:4444/session/eaed604c5fae33476755e4ba3e1c1d9e/se/cdp"


$setWindowRect
[1] TRUE

$strictFileInteractability
[1] FALSE

$timeouts
$timeouts$implicit
[1] 0

$timeouts$pageLoad
[1] 300000

$timeouts$script
[1] 30000


$unhandledPromptBehavior
[1] "dismiss and notify"

$`webauthn:extension:largeBlob`
[1] TRUE

$`webauthn:virtualAuthenticators`
[1] TRUE

$id
[1] "eaed604c5fae33476755e4ba3e1c1d9e"
```